# Why this error (text and text are incompatible?)

Tags: t-sql

please help,

I am unsure why I keep getting this error 'The data types text and text are incompatible in the equal to operator.'

When I run this code it works;

```
SELECT  [startername]
        ,[endername]
FROM [master].[dbo].[MATCH]
WHERE enderpoints = 0.0
```

When I run this code it works;

```
SELECT name FROM PLAYERS WHERE TEAM like 'Stars' OR TEAM like 'Aces'
```

When I try to do both I get an error, what am I missing?

```
SELECT  [startername]
        ,[endername]
FROM [master].[dbo].[MATCH]
WHERE enderpoints = 0.0
AND startername IN (SELECT name FROM PLAYERS WHERE team like 'Stars' OR team like 'Aces')
```

Comment: `tsql`? Tag your question's RDBMS as indicated by the `sql` tag.

Comment: Without the DDL it's hard to say why `Match.StarterName` might be incompatible with `Players.Name`, if that's really where the problem occurs. Aside: Using `like` without wildcards in the pattern is very much like using `=`, e.g. `where team = 'Stars' or team = 'Aces'`. Another alternative is `where team in ( 'Stars', 'Aces' )`.

Comment: Still the same error - is there any additional info I can give that might help?

Comment: The error message is telling you what happen. You are comparing `text` data type with `text` data type. You cannot use `text` data with comparison operators. Convert the `text` to `varchar(max)` before comparing

Comment: @Valador1988 There is additional information you can provide: DDL for the tables. As Squirrel pointed out, [Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "can be used on all expressions except expressions of the `text`, `ntext`, or `image` data types."

Comment: ```TEXT``` is soft-deprecated and has a lot of quirks that I'd highly recommend never using it. Should use ```VARCHAR``` instead (if possible). Also why are you using ```master``` db to store user tables? Generally recommend not using system db's to store user data